# Changing data in another PFuser object

Tags: parse-platform

In my game, a user can cause damage to another user, and take some of their gold. The gold variable is stored in the other users PFUser object. How can one user change the value for the gold that is stored in the other users PFUser's object?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: Not exactly I just avoided the situation, by removing all the objects that might need to be interacted with by other players outside of the PFUser class.

Comment: That's what I figured, and that's the route I'm having to take. I guess it's understandable, but annoying none the less.

Comment: Hmm it's probably for the best, that way only objects that the player themselves can change is in the PFUser.

Answer (score 11):

You can not save or delete non-authenticated PFUsers. The way to implement that functionality is to set up a separate class for public read/write user variables

From the parse documentation -

> Security For User Objects
>
> The PFUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a PFUser can
>   only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read
>   by any client. Thus, some PFUser objects are authenticated and can be
>   modified, whereas others are read-only.
>
> Specifically, you are not able to invoke any of the save or delete
>   methods unless the PFUser was obtained using an authenticated method,
>   like logIn or signUp. This ensures that only the user can alter their
>   own data.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can't even change the user's attributes, because it will not save the changes.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution would be to handle it with a cloud code. Manipulating a non authenticated PFUser object from client side will raise some security issues. Have a cloud function like:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("stealGold", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.targetObjectId);
    query.find({useMasterKey : true}).then(function(results) {
    // process the result of the query here
    // Save the user object

    });
  });
```

You may read about it in docs here: https://parse.com/docs/data#security-cloudcode

Answer (score 0):

You could use [getUserObjectWithId](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/getUserObjectWithId%3a), from PFQuery.

Comment: I know how to get a PFuser object, but I don't know how (or if it's possible) to change the data of one PFUser object from another, without some kind of special access being granted, but I don't know how that is done.

Comment: Have you tried the usual way of referencing it ie userObj["gold"]?