# ACL Role for admin in parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, admin, acl

Struggling to get this working, lack of understanding, but if anyone could help me to get there, that would be great. Currently I have a user logging in as an administrator by just setting a boolean, this works fine:

```
if (authority == "true"){

    let acl = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()) // Only user can write
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(true) // Everybody can read
        acl.setWriteAccess(true, forUser: PFUser.currentUser()) // Also
    var role:PFRole = PFRole(name: "Administator", acl: acl)
        role.users.addObject(PFUser.currentUser())
        role.saveInBackground()

    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Admin")
        self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
}
```

This sets an admin role in my parse database. What I am trying to do is to give privileges to this user so that he could edit all other users e.g. giving points to the students for the correctly completed tasks.

```
if let object = userObject?{
println(tasksCorrect)
object["tasksCorrect"] = tasksCorrect + 1
println(object)
object.saveInBackground()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that user objects have an ACL that includes read/write access for the "Administrator" role.

Comment: I've worked out this issue, after not reading thoroughly through the security part of the Parse API. What i was trying to edit was the objects inside the user class, this isn't allowed, without workarounds like using cloud code or actually knowing the users objectId which for queries wouldn't work effectively.  As i found in this link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345311/changing-data-in-another-pfuser-object